# Angular Animate 1.58 not calling addClass function in animation module

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I am trying to add some javascript animations in my angular 1.58 app but I can't seem to get it to work. I need to use a third party library called Vivus to animate an SVG when the directive it is in loads.  I have added angular animate, I have included a reference to it in my module and I have added an animation function to my module with an addClass function to it.  The SVG has an ng-class on it which gets a class added to it when the code runs but the addClass function never fires.  My code is written in Typescript and I can't find any examples of doing this in Typescript so that may be the problem. The code is as follows

```
<div class="banner-colour">
<br>
<br>
<svg ng-class="{{$ctrl.bannerClass}}" class="banner-change" id="vivusanimated" width="47" height="47" viewBox="0 0 47 47" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><path id="a" d="M6.922 6.922h32.906v32.906H6.922z"/><mask id="b" x="0" y="0" width="32.906" height="32.906" fill="#fff"><use xlink:href="#a"/></mask></defs><g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" opacity=".5"><use stroke="#FFF" mask="url(#b)" stroke-width="2" transform="rotate(45 23.374 23.374)" xlink:href="#a"/><g fill="#FFF"><path d="M15.222 25.12l.707-.706 5.656 5.657-.707.708z"/><path d="M20.172 30.07l9.9-9.898.706.707-9.9 9.898z"/></g></g></svg>
<br>
<br>
</div>
```

The animation module looks like this

```
namespace app {
"use strict";

declare var Vivus: any;

angular.module("app").animation(".banner-change", function(): any {
     return {


        addClass: function(element: any, className: any, done: any): any {

            let vivus: any = new Vivus("vivusanimated", {duration: 300}, done);
        }
     };
});
}
```

The controller for the component looks like this

namespace app.main.home {
    "use strict";

```
interface IBannerComponentBindings {

}

interface IBannerComponentController extends IBannerComponentBindings {
    bannerClass: string;
}

class BannerComponentController implements IBannerComponentController {

    public bannerClass: string;

    constructor() {
        this.bannerClass = "banner-graphic";
    }

}

class BannerComponent implements ng.IComponentOptions {

    public bindings: any;
    public controller: any;
    public templateUrl: string;

    constructor() {
        this.bindings = {
        };

        this.controller = BannerComponentController;
        this.templateUrl = "app/main/home/banner.html";
    }

}

angular.module("app.main.home").component("ylBanner", new BannerComponent());
}
```

I've tried tying the animations to different modules but that didn't help so I have run out of ideas.

If anyone knows what I am doing wrong please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to the bottom of this after going though a lot of documentation and courses and I needed to do the add the data-ng-animate-children tag to my top level view like so

```
<div data-ui-view data-ng-animate-children></div>
```

I also added the $animate.enabled(true) to the run function of my top level module like so

```
run.$inject = ["$animate", "$window", "$rootScope"];
function run($animate: ng.animate.IAnimateService, $window: any, $rootScope: ng.IRootScopeService, $location: ng.ILocationService): void {
    $animate.enabled(true);
}
```

This allowed the animations to run as the web page is loading in the browser.  After that the rest of the angular animate stuff worked as usual.